# How to prevent blisters on plam during normal excercises such as dumb bells

Tags: pull-ups, dumbbells, chest, gloves

I normally lift dumb bells of about 7-8 kg(5 sets with 10 each) and later do pull-ups (2 sets of 25 with a gap in between)and later the chest press(2 sets of 25 with upto 20 kgs).Although in all these exercises the palm plays a vital role in grip it also causes blisters in the hand (the area just below the fingers).

These blisters are worsened by the automotive breaking.I would like to know is there any sort of exercise to reduce it or avoid it if possible.

**Update**:-
Is wearing gym glove a better alternative to chalking the hands.(Chalking may cause some dust allergies to my hands or to others nearby)

Comment: RE: Update... NO!  Gloves actually make it worse by making it harder to grip the bar and easier to pinch the skin.  That results in more callouses, and added friction increases the chance of blisters... but now with more opportunities (like between fingers).

Answer (score 4):

There are two main hazards for your hands when gripping things: developing callouses and blisters.  If you have blisters (area of skin covering a pocket of puss), it is because you are letting the implement move in your hand.

The way to *minimize* callouses and *prevent* blisters is to learn how to grip the implement so it doesn't move in your hand:

- If you are performing a pulling movement, place the hand on the implement so the pad (area of the palm where your fingers are attached) is in contact.  Wrap the fingers and rest of the grip around the bar in such a way that you are compressing, but not pinching the pad of your hand.
- If you are performing a pushing movement, place the implement in the palm of your hand so that it rests in the crook of your thumb and the base of the palm.  Wrap your fingers and grip the implement so that the bar, dumbbell, handle is fully supported by palm where it connects to the wrist.
- In either case, grip the implement **tightly** so that it does not move around in your hand.

Even without chalk, just learning to properly grip the implements can prevent blisters altogether and minimize callouses.  That said, anything to help your hands remain dry during exercise will improve your grip, and consequently further reduce callouses and blisters.  In the order of preference:

- Chalk.  This is the gold standard used by gymnasts, Olympic weightlifters, power lifters, and just about any sport where strength over your own body and other implements is required.
- Eco ball by Metoleus.  It's a chalk alternative that produces less mess.  It works, but not as well as chalk.
- Liquid chalk.  It's a chalk alternative that doesn't leave any residue behind.  It does keep your hands nice and dry though.
- Athletic tape.  Tape works well when you have raw areas that need to be protected, but it doesn't do much for a sweaty hand.
- A stack of fresh towels.  You're going to sweat if you are doing things right, which means you'll have to keep drying your hands.

You'll notice that gloves are not on this list.  Gloves actually make the situation worse:

- Gloves make your hands sweat more, causing the bar to move more in your palm.
- Gloves make gripping harder in general, causing the conditions that make blisters and callouses happen more often.
- Gloves introduce new points of friction, meaning new places you can get blisters that you couldn't get if you didn't wear them.  A prime example would be the area between your fingers.

Blisters have to be removed.  The best thing to do is to pop the blister, clean it, and use athletic tape while you train.  Then clean it again and cover it with a band aid.  They should heal pretty quickly as long as it doesn't get infected.

Callouses just have to be controlled.  When they start getting too big, take a pumice stone to grind off the excess but don't completely remove it.  Applying lotion after you clean up from exercise can also help.

Comment: could you please give the proper gripping technique with an image describing exact pressure points which lead to this pus pocket's or blister and the exact way in which the person bends down and grips the weights

Comment: Some times I tend to over-grip (When increasing my weights during initial days i apply a lot of pressure at my fingers to grip the weight properly) maybe that could alleviate the already present condition

Comment: For pulling movements: http://cdn.stronglifts.com/wp-content/uploads/deadlift-proper-grip1.jpg

Comment: For pressing movements: http://stronglifts.com/wp-content/uploads/bench-press-setup.jpg

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your fingers around the bar and grip tightly.

Answer (score 2):

Trim your blisters with a nail clipper. There is no quick fix to this being difficult: either wait for the blister to heal or deal with the pain.

Buy a brick of chalk. (It should be a buck or two for something the size of your fist.) Chalk your hands, particularly your fingers and the spots that blister. Chalk keeps your hand dry and prevents folds in your grip, both of which cause blisters.

I don't see the point of gym gloves. Chalk works.

Comment: tried cutting the blisters with the nail clipper but the blisters are somewhat tight /pain full to come off.Have to try trimming now btw how does chalking avoid blisters and what about the use of Gym gloves

Comment: Check the updated post

Comment: and now check *my* updated post

Comment: Any pointers for helping him grip the implements better?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Not really...I trim calluses/blisters, I chalk, and I don't think too much about grip beyond "does it feel right?" and "do I need to hook grip this set?".